# How to create a custom list field when using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following model and I would like to add a custom field called `choices` which will be a list of choices.

```
class HPIQuestionBank(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        db_index=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True)
    template = models.ForeignKey(
        HPIFilter, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
```

I have implemented the following in the serializers.

```
class CheckBoxesListField(serializers.ListField):
    child = serializers.CharField(allow_null = True, allow_blank=True)

class TemplateQuestionBankSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answer_type = serializers.CharField(allow_null = True, allow_blank=True)
    checkboxes = CheckBoxesListField()

    hpianswers_set =TemplateAnswerSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = HPIQuestionBank
        fields = ['id','label','hpianswers_set','answer_type','checkboxes']
```

I'm using the serializer on my `GET` method. When I attempt to make a request I get the following error:

```
AttributeError at /api/clinic2/history/template/6/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `checkboxes` on serializer `TemplateQuestionBankSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `HPIQuestionBank` instance.
Original exception text was: 'HPIQuestionBank' object has no attribute 'checkboxes'.
```

Comment: what purpose of your `checkboxes`? Only for get data?

Comment: I would like to use it when I create the PUT method for updating

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read data only you can try:

```
class Meta:
    model = HPIQuestionBank
    fields = ['id','label','hpianswers_set','answer_type',]
    read_only_fields = ['checkboxes',]
```

Or you can work with `SerializerMethodField` as

```
class TemplateQuestionBankSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answer_type = serializers.CharField(allow_null = True, allow_blank=True)
    checkboxes = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_checkboxes(self, instance):
        return CheckBoxesListField(instance).data
```

Comment: I got  the following AttributeError : 'CheckBoxesListField' object has no attribute 'data'